# object oriented inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am studying ways to apply Object Orientation in JavaScript.
I found a solution to use inheritance, I wonder if there is better ways and how to wrap my classes.

That's what I've done so far.

```
People = function (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = null;
};

Employee = function (name) {
    People.call(this, name);
    this.IdentificationCode = null;
    this.salary = null;
}

Jonh = new Employee("Jonh Smith");
Jonh.age = 25;
Jonh.IdentificationCode = 35632;
Jonh.salary = 3500;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code, it should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The call part runs the instance specific part of inheritance. You can inherit behavior through prototype for more info please read the following answer.http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** You are not inheriting from `People`, but you are reusing `People`'s constructor function.

**Suggestion 1:**

Make sure that you are not creating global variables.

```
var People = function (name) {     // var at the beginning is important
...
...
var Employee = function (name) {   // var at the beginning is important
...
...
var Jonh = new Employee("Jonh Smith");
```

**Suggestion 2:**

The constructor function should have a way to initialize other variables as well.

```
var People = function (name, age) {
    this.name = name || null;
    this.age  = age || null;
};
var Employee = function (name, age, idCode, salary) {
    People.call(this, name, age);
    this.IdentificationCode = idCode || null;
    this.salary = salary || null;
}
```

As `People` doesn't have any methods in its prototype, this should be fine.

But if you have methods in `People`'s prototype and you want them to be available to your derived *objects* as well, you can do this

```
var People = function (name, age) {
    this.name = name || null;
    this.age  = age || null;
};

People.prototype.getData = function() {
    return [this.name, this.age];
};
```

Now define `Employee` like this

```
var Employee = function (name, age, idCode, salary) {
    People.call(this, name, age);
    this.IdentificationCode = idCode;
    this.salary = salary;
}

// Make the Employee's prototype an object of parent class's prototype
Employee.prototype = Object.create(People.prototype);
```

Then do,

```
var Jonh = new Employee("Jonh Smith", 25, 35632, 3500);
console.log(Jonh.getData());
```

Now, it will invoke `People`'s `getData` and will print

```
[ 'Jonh Smith', 25 ]
```

**Note:** This type of inheritance is normally called as Prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Better not create an instance of parent to set prototype part of inheritance

Comment: @HMR `Employee.prototype = Object.create(People.prototype);`?

Comment: Yes, now it's a perfect example.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}


function Employee(name, age) {
    Person.call(this, name, age);
    this.salary = null;
}


Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

var teste = new Employee("Felipe",25)
teste instanceof Employee // true
teste instanceof Person // true
```

Object.create is making heritage. Object.create receives an object and returns another whose prototype is the object passed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Employee` to inherit from `People` using `Object.create`.

```
var People = function (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = null;
};

var Employee = function (name) {
    People.call(this, name);
    this.IdentificationCode = null;
    this.salary = null;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(People.prototype); // create a new object inheriting from People.prototype
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee; // put the constructor back

var Jonh = new Employee("Jonh Smith");
Jonh.age = 25;
Jonh.IdentificationCode = 35632;
Jonh.salary = 3500;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. One is the same you did.
Another is to use the prototype object:

```
Employee.prototype = new People();
```

You can also use functions that return newly created objects, and call one from another:

```
function getPeople ( name ) {
    var result;
    result.name = name;
    result.age = null;

    return result;
}

function getEmployee ( name ) {
    var result = getPeople ( name );
    result.IdentificationCode = null;
    result.salary = null;

    return result;
}
```